# Can't pick minDate in momentjs

Tags: javascript, php, datepicker, momentjs

I'm using a date picker to let the user select a date between 100 days in the past and today. It works fine, but there is an issue I can't solve.
Apparently, minDate is calculated and applied correctly in the picker. Dates which are older than 100 days are shown in gray and not selectable. The problem is that the first available day, shown in black, is not selectable neither. When the pointer hovers such date, it correctly turns to a hand, but when clicked, the picker closes and shows current date instead.
All other dates, from the second oldest, work properly.

```js
<!--Campo de fecha-->
    <div class="form-group" <?php echo $mostrarDiv; ?>>
        <div>
            <label for="fecha" class="etiquetaDeCampo"><span class="fas fa-calendar-day"></span> Selecciona la fecha del suceso:</label>
            <div class="msgError" id="errorFecha">
                <p>Selecciona la fecha.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
            if(isset($_SESSION['fecha']) && $_SESSION['fecha'] != ""){
                $fecha = $_SESSION['fecha'];
            } else {
                $fecha = "";
            }
            $fecha = 'value="'.$fecha.'"';
        ?>
        <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker" data-target-input="nearest">
                                                
                <input type="text" name="fecha" id="fecha" class="form-control datetimepicker-input campoDeDatos" data-toggle="datetimepicker" data-target="#datetimepicker" <?php echo $fecha; ?>/>
                <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#datetimepicker" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
                    <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
                </div>
            
        </div>
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var dateFormat = "DD-MM-YYYY";
        var CurrDate = new Date();
        var limitePasado = new Date();
        limitePasado.setDate(limitePasado.getDate() - 100);

        dateCurr = moment(CurrDate, dateFormat);
        $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
            format: 'DD-MMM-YYYY',
            locale: 'es',
            defaultDate: CurrDate,
            showToday: true,
            maxDate: dateCurr,
            minDate: limitePasado,
        });
    });
</script>
<!--Fin de fecha-->
```

Comment: Probably unrelated, but just FYI, your `<div></div>` tags are unbalanced

Comment: They look unbalanced, but they are ok. That's because the code was misplaced when pasted. I'll format it properly.

Comment: Unless there is additional HTML that you are omitting, then they are _not_ balanced.  You will see this if you create a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) to demonstrate your problem.  And instead of showing us `<?php echo $fecha; ?>` could you show what the actual rendered output would be there?

Comment: You are right. There was an extra closing tag related to additional code above. It's not there anymore. The original code is balanced, and it was a paste problem.

Comment: try minDate: new Date(limitePasado)...

Comment: So this is _not_ the actual code that you're using?  It is really hard to debug something we can't see.

Comment: @PatrickQ it is the actual code. I made a trim to make it easer to readers. I included the whole div now.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var CurrDate = moment();
 var limitePasado = moment().subtract(100, "days");
```

also try

```
maxDate: moment(),
minDate: moment().subtract(100, "days"),
```

use this

Comment: Still the same.